# Not Working My Many to Many Relestionship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Not working my many to many relationship  hmcs_tender is my table name
This is My Airportcode model

```
class AirPortCode extends Model
        {
         Protected $table = 'hmsc_air_port_codes';
         public $timestamps = false;
         Protected $primaryKey = 'id';

         public function airPorts()
        {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Admin_Module\TenderMaster','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','bid_id','port_id');
        }

        }
```

This is my Model(TenderModel.php)

```
class TenderMaster extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hmcs_tender';
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $primarykey = 'id';

  public function bits()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Masters\Air\AirPortCode','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','port_id','bid_id');
}

}
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with SQL?

Comment: what is "not working"? and is `hmcs_tender` the correct name? the other tables are prefixed with `hmsc_`

Comment: yeah hmcs_tender is my table name and its correct .. not working many to many relationship and i also use artisan tinker to check my relationship and artisan is show null value in my relationship

Comment: What is the error? Because 'not working' can be many things. Laravel has probably given you an error code or error message.

Comment: @Vivekkalanka `Relationship does not work`. Does that mean that php gives an error? Or that you dont get the results you expect?

Comment: Kindly explain further, what kind of error you are facing.